# run ms-dos file on free web hosting ( tomcat )

Tags: java, tomcat7, dos, openshift, dosbox

I´m doing a lab in which I have to wrap a legacy app ( in **MS-DOS** ) and deploy that on a web server. Actually I´m achieving that using Tomcat, DOSBox ( MS-DOS emulator ) and Java EE on Windows .

I was wondering if it was possible to deploy that on a **free web hosting** , like OpenShift ( I already tried deploying Servlets and JSP's to OpenShift before but didn´t have to run any external apps ).

I tried connecting to OpenShift via SSH and install SDL and DOSBox but it allways fails ( seems like problems with SDL ) , probably because of driver incompatibility .

So, does anybody have an idea of how would it be possible to achieve my goal of desploying that Java wrapper for and MS-DOS app in a free web hosting ?

Comment: How are you going to talk to the legacy app, since MS-DOS doesn't have any built-in support for networking (yes, this is really true!)

Comment: @RobinGreen I´m talking to the legacy app with the help of java.awt.Robot :) I just run the app and the servlets use the java robot to simulate the keyboard to control the app and dispaly the results in the web.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a free host that has Xvfb installed. Use Xvfb to bring up a virtual display, and then set the DISPLAY variable to make Dosbox connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

doesn't SDL require OpenGL? 
that requirement may be the issue with the install.
i've been trying to figure out how to do something similar without java--[in my case i do not need to see console output from the DOS application]